# What does an SQL Injection query such as below means? What will be the answer of this

Tags: sql, sql-injection

```
 ' AND ascii(substring((SELECT concat(login,0x3a,password) from users limit 0,1),1,1))>96#
```

I am working on bee box machine and practicing blind SQL injection. I know what the ascii and substring does, I also know what concat does, but why we are concatenating the login and password together since we have to generate a single ascii character?why we had 1,1 in the end.

Comment: the 1,1 are arguments in the SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @LONG I have seen the answer you suggested above, I did not find it relevant to the one I have asked here.

Comment: @JGautam, ok, then my answer might be helpful regardless of the injection

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for answering, also can you tell me what would be the output of this and why the first characters of both login and passwords are taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will attempt to get a 'user' and 'password' from the first row of a table called 'users', concat them with a colon in the middle (dave:passw), then takes the first character of that, and tests if that first character is a lowercase letter, or the characters { | } ~

No idea why that information would be useful to an attacker, but sometimes a whole battery of tests adds up to information even though each test in isolation is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check the full ASCII code here:

https://www.ascii-code.com/

As you can see from the web, the ASCII code 96 is

> `

any character after that (ASCII number larger than 96) are valid English characters (in lower case) regardless of those special symbols, which means for you secure login user, at least it should be a person name start with those characters (in lower case).

So you were taking the first character of your concatenated login string by `SUBSTRING(long_string,1,1)`, which is trying to validate if the login person's account start with a English character(in lower case)